# WPF - Command not responding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, command

I have the following code in which DeleteBelegkopfCommand is not responding when clicking the MenuItem:

```
[...]
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
            <Image Margin="0,0,2,2"  
                   Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},
                                    Path=Header, Converter={x:Static conv:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding BelegtypDesc, StringFormat='Beleg: {0}'}"
                            acb:LeftClickCommands.MouseEventParameter="{Binding}" 
                            acb:LeftClickCommands.MouseLeftButtonClickCommand="{Binding ElementName=CaseTreeView, Path=DataContext.ChangeSelectionCommand}">
                 </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>                            
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Beleg löschen"
                              Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.DeleteBelegkopfCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=CurrentBelegkopf.Id}">
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
```

This is where I define the Command. CanDeleteBelegkopf is always true for testing:

```
static DelegateCommand<Guid?> _deleteBelegkopfCommand;

public DelegateCommand<Guid?> DeleteBelegkopfCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_deleteBelegkopfCommand == null)
            _deleteBelegkopfCommand = new DelegateCommand<Guid?>(OnDeleteBelegkopf, CanDeleteBelegkopf);
        return _deleteBelegkopfCommand;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why my command is not responding at all? I tested it with other commands which are working at other places in my code - it didn't work either. So I think it's something about my Binding with the command.

Answer (score 1):

ContextMenus are separate controls with their own VisualTree:

If you look in the output window, i am guessing you see binding exceptions. If so, then have a look at :

http://www.wpftutorial.net/RoutedCommandsInContextMenu.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already binded the CommandTarget manually as mentioned in the wpftutorial:

RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}

As written in the tutorial, it should work like this. Unfortunately it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have a look at Visual Studio output Window to see if any binding exception is being thrown when you click on the menu item. I suspect Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.DeleteBelegkopfCommand

Comment: There is no exception nor any text about DeleteBelefkopfCommand when I'm searching with CTRL+F in the output. :( When I', clicking the MenuItem, absolutely nothing happens in the output.

Comment: I suggest you simplify it a bit for now by removing the CommandParameter. Instead add a CommandTarget as shown in  http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/06/19/1097-getting-items-in-context-menu-to-correctly-use-command-binding/ and add the context menu as its target. Then Change the Command to Command="{Binding DeleteBelegkopfCommand} ... The CommandTarget should set the Command datacontext to that of the ContextMenu.

Comment: That's a good idea, but it didn't help. I'm now getting an exception for my binding:

BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteBelegkopfCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Belegkopf' (HashCode=46816480)'. BindingExpression:Path=DeleteBelegkopfCommand; DataItem='Belegkopf' (HashCode=46816480); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Ok that means the DataContext for the menu item is Belegkopf but , but Belegkopf does not contain any public property that returns DeleteBelegkopfCommand command.I am guessing you want to bind to Belegkopf collection.